# Присвоение значений свойству объекта в массиве

Tags: php, массивы, объекты

Есть такая конструкция

```
$params = array ("Id"=>"{$deal_id}", "program"=>"2","Positions"=>array(array("OfferId"=>"89", "Count"=> "$total_area"), array("OfferId"=>"124", "Count"=> "$total_reika"), array("OfferId"=>"125", "Count"=> "$total_lightnings")));
        $Price = new stdClass();
        $Price->Value = 100; 
        $params[Positions][0][Price] = $Price;
        $Price->Value = 200;
        $params[Positions][1][Price] = $Price;
        $Price->Value = 300;
        $params[Positions][2][Price] = $Price;
```

Вот что выводит print_r($params)

```
Array
(
    [Id] => 531
    [program] => 2
    [Positions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [OfferId] => 89
                    [Count] => 20
                    [Price] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Value] => 300
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [OfferId] => 124
                    [Count] => 1
                    [Price] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Value] => 300
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [OfferId] => 125
                    [Count] => 1
                    [Price] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Value] => 300
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Почему значение Price->Value у всех позиций равно 300?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому, что в массив помещается **указатель** на однажды созданный объект `Price`, а потом у этого объекта последовательно изменяется поле `Value`.

Чтобы такого не происходило, Вам нужно каждый раз создавать новый объект или клонировать предыдущий

```
$Price = new stdClass();
$Price->Value = 100; 
$params['Positions'][0]['Price'] = clone $Price;
$Price->Value = 200;
$params['Positions'][1]['Price'] = clone $Price;
```

Подробнее в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.cloning.php)

P.S. Строковые имена индексов массивов настоятельно рекомендуется писать [в кавычках](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php)

> Почему $foo[bar] неверно?
>   Всегда заключайте в кавычки строковый литерал в индексе ассоциативного массива. К примеру, пишите `$foo['bar']`, а не `$foo[bar]`. Но почему? Часто в старых скриптах можно встретить следующий синтаксис:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $foo[bar] = 'враг';
> echo $foo[bar];
> // и т.д.
> ?>
> ```
>
> Это неверно, хотя и работает. Причина в том, что этот код содержит неопределенную константу (`bar`), а не строку (`'bar'` - обратите внимание на кавычки). Это работает, потому что PHP автоматически преобразует "голую строку" (не заключенную в кавычки строку, которая не соответствует ни одному из известных символов языка) в строку со значением этой "голой строки". Например, если константа с именем `bar` не определена, то PHP заменит `bar` на строку `'bar'` и использует ее.

Answer (score 0):

Все понятно. Все Positions в массиве ссылаются на один и тот же объект. Исправлено добавлением $Price = new stdClass() перед каждым присвоением значения